# handle click event to remove the specific tr in table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know why click event doesn't work though it works itself in `fiddle`.
I have a modal that contains categories which are have their childrens .
I get json array and convert it to php array.
I wrote functions. one of them implements to select/deselect childrens . e.g. if you select/deselect the parent category, it's children will be selected/deselected and also shown in the table below. but the problem is when users click on the `class="fa fa-times"` it doesn't remove the specific tr of the table.
I emphasize once again that all things go well except the last script.
what's wrong with it?

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="permissionDlg" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Please click to expand it.</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
    <form method="post" action="index.php"  class="form-horizontal">

        <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 10px;">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Assign Permission" />
        </div>            
    <div >
        <div class=" tree">
<ul>
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="set here from the php array">
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="set here from the php array">
</form>
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Main Category</td>
            <td>1 level </td>
            <td>2 level </td>
            <td>3 level </td>
            <td>Delete </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbl_permission">

    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
  </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>

       $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.fa.fa-times').click(function(){
                $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 
            });
       }); 




</script>
```

Comment: @choz. I'm John. this is the full code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I emphasize once again that all things go well except the last script. what's wrong with it?

This is because the elements come later into the DOM (dynamic elements) and they do not exist on document ready event where you try to bind events to `fa fa-times`. That's why the event is not even applied on those elements and hence it doesn't work.

Solution: Use **event delegation**

```
        $('table').on('click','.fa.fa-times',function(){
            $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 
        });
```

Comment: is there any way to send each values of table as an array to server. I mean I put the table inside form and each rows has the value which is unique. finally when he wants to submits the form , just sent the value inside of the table. in additional info each rows has value like `cat_id=1+childrens=2+subchild=5`